# Google Sheets Script Needed: On Insert_Row, set multiple formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Novice Google Apps Scripter here,

I have an IFTTT applet which adds a row to this spreadsheet via email: [Data Test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJKiDNPUWMMUbLLb-UDA6iRA2PBnlMHDsEB9vELe0Rk/edit?usp=sharing)

I seem to have the formulas set up correctly, but when a new row is added, the formulas obviously do not auto-populate into that new row. When a row is inserted, in which the corresponding cells in Columns A and B are not blank, I'd like set certain formulas in that row.

The script I have so far (see below) does give me the formulas I want, but only in Row1. 
I'd like the script to set those same formulas into corresponding cells of any new row that is inserted.

For example, if I were to insert a blank row after Row5 (i.e., create a new Row6), then the formulas will appear in C6:H6

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var cell = sheet.getRange("C1");
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B2,SEARCH("details",$B2)+7,SEARCH(",",$B2)-SEARCH("details",$B2)-7),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
  var cell = sheet.getRange("D1");
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B2,FIND("$",B2),LEN(B2))," ",REPT(" ",100)),100)),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
  var cell = sheet.getRange("E1");
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B2,SEARCH("exceed",$B2)+7,SEARCH("%",$B2)-SEARCH("exceed",$B2)-6),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
  var cell = sheet.getRange("F1");
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B2,SEARCH("due",$B2)+3,SEARCH(";",$B2)-SEARCH("due",$B2)-3),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
  var cell = sheet.getRange("G1");
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B2,SEARCH("held on",$B2)+7,SEARCH(". Lottery",$B2)-SEARCH("held on",$B2)-7),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
  var cell = sheet.getRange("H1");
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B2,SEARCH("posted by",$B2)+9,SEARCH(". ",$B2)-SEARCH("",$B2)-167),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');

}
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I recommend that you read this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) it's very well written and very well organized.  When your finished reading then try to write the script yourself and if you have any trouble come back with a copy of what you've done and then we can help you.

Comment: Looks well written and well organized. However, it's still like Greek to me. Can anyone get me started?

Comment: Start by writing a script to set formulas, then add an onEdit Trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a start for your script. It is how you assign a formula to a cell.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var cell = sheet.getRange("C1");
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B2,SEARCH("details",$B2)+7,SEARCH(",",$B2)-SEARCH("details",$B2)-7),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
}
```

Comment: That's definitely a great start! Added edits based on @OblongMedulla. Not quite what I need yet.

Comment: Wonder if @Cooper can chime in?